# Create automated git commits into a branch created only for them, in parallel to the usual manual commits

Tags: git, automation

In addition to the normal, manual git commits I'm doing in a project, I also want to start adding automated commits, for example every 30 minutes.

These automated commits should be clearly separated from the normal ones. I was thinking about two approaches:

- rsync all the files except any git-related files and directories into another directory, and have that directory have it's own repository, which creates the automated commits on the master branch.
- create a new branch labeled "automated" and commit into that branch.

The first approach is trivial, but I want to test if the second one isn't a better alternative, yet I don't know how to do this.

How can I, step by step, commit into that "automated" branch, and afterwards ensure that if I create a manual commit, it behaves just like a normal commit, as if that "automated" branch didn't exist.

It should even be so that the manual commits don't contain just the difference between the last automated commit, but the entire changes since the last manual commit.

The automated commits should just contain the changes since the last commit, be it a manual one or an automated one (but it would also be ok if the last manual commit would be ignored).

The automated commit should only be created if changes have been made since the last commit, be it a manual one or an automated one.

Or is the second approach a bad one so that I shouldn't even consider it? I would probably use Python with [`dulwich`](https://github.com/dulwich/dulwich) for this automation.

Comment: What kind of extra changes would be added to the manual commits by this automated process ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sideband index and construct the commits directly, (fingers-to-textbox warning…)

```
#!/bin/sh
base=`git rev-parse 2>&- timed-commits || git rev-parse @`
GIT_INDEX_FILE=`git rev-parse --git-dir`/timed-index || { echo couldn\'t get git dir; exit; }
export GIT_INDEX_FILE
while sleep $((30*60)); do
        git add .
        git update-ref -m 'automatic timed commit' refs/heads/timed-commits $(
                git commit-tree -p $base -m 'timed commit' `git write-tree`
        )
done &
```

The `git add .` will add everything that isn't ignored in whatever work tree you run it in. To only add what's already tracked, switch to `git add -a`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasonable approaches here: one with a worktree with your `automated` branch checked out, and the other using a branch that's not checked out.

For the former, you can create a worktree, copy files over (using `rsync` or similar), and then commit on a periodic basis.  Git only stores full snapshots of your changes, so any commit you make (anywhere, anytime) will contain a full snapshot of changes.

Alternatively, you can use a library like libgit2 (or possibly Dulwich) to add commits to an `automated` branch without ever having it checked out.  You'd create a temporary index and add the files that are currently in the existing index (or clone the index to an in-memory copy), and then create a new commit on the `automated` branch.  You could technically do this with command-line Git as well by copying the index file somewhere else, setting `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to point to the new index file, using `git commit-tree` to write the commit, and then using `git update-ref` to update the `automated` branch.

By not checking out the `automated` branch (or using a separate worktree), you'll commit into the same branch you always have (the one checked out) when you make a manual commit.

Both of these will require a decent amount of scripting.  My personal suggestion would be to investigate the unchecked out branch approach and see if that's possible in your scenario.